# Couldn't create subscription. Your account has reached its subscription limit. To create more subscriptions, contact Azure support

Tags: azure, azure-subscription, azure-management-groups

I am trying to create azure subscription from api. After making api request, I got this error saying:

"(NotAllowed) Couldn't create subscription. Your account has reached its subscription limit. To create more subscriptions, contact Azure support. Code: NotAllowed Message: Couldn't create subscription. Your account has reached its subscription limit. To create more subscriptions, contact Azure support.".

I currently have 10 subscription created under my root management group and I did not find anything in the documentation that mentions any limit on subscription under specific management group.

These are some references that I went through related to limits in azure.

[Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits)

[Billing accounts and scopes in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/view-all-accounts)

I didn't find anything related to subscription limits other than that.
If anyone is able to guide or help it would be great. Thanks

Comment: The error message says to contact Azure support. Have you contacted them?

Comment: No I haven't but at least I should know what is the source of this error

Answer (score 0):

You are right , You can create multiple subscriptions associated with an Azure Active Directory tenant and  Limits for other areas apply as in [Azure subscription limits and quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#subscription-limits)

Error causes: [SubscriptionPolicyCountExceeded exceptions in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/cloud-services/troubleshoot-subscription-policy)
[image]

But a Maximum of only one subscription can be repeated in the span of 24 hour period. [message-create multiple subscriptions - Microsoft Cost Management | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/create-subscriptions-deploy-resources)

Also, Your admin might have restricted the subscription creation limit through policies.
It's important to note that Azure has certain limits and quotas which can vary depending on factors such as subscription type, account type, and usage patterns.
The limit can be exceeded when the billing cost is limited or restricted to a particular amount by Administrator.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/create-subscriptions-deploy-resources

Comment: I still didn't get it. Is it because of the last statement? "Location of Subscription-level-deployements". Because what I understood by reading it is that it is talking about depoyments using ARM templates. Is it so? And what does location means here?